# Sending mail through C# with gmail not working online

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, mailmessage

I am trying to send mail through gmail. I am sending mail successfully when I am testing on localhost, but this does not work when I upload online. Below is my code used to send email. Any help please ?

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.From = new MailAddress("donotreply@gmail.com");
            mm.Subject = "Test";
            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
            mm.Body = "Test";
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("donotreply@gmail.com", "password");
            client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: Where online are you uploading your files? It could be that the firewall is blocking that specific port. (587)

Comment: Aren't there any kind of log you can get from the server ? Like the security log.

Comment: Does not work isn't a good error description. Look at the error it shoud contain a hint of what the problem is. A guess would be that the smtp service simply isn't running.

Comment: I don't know the error as I have an error page and if I remove that I will still get something on web config custom errors

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like it may be answered by this similar StackOverflow question:

[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Let me know if that does not answer all of your questions.

Comment: no still not working after using that answer's code :/ works on localhost but not online

Answer (score 0):

In your current code above, you first set:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true
```

which tells the framework to use the default credentials, and then you go on to define your custom credentials:

```
 client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("donotreply@gmail.com", "password");
```

Which it will not use when it tries to send mail, because you've already told it to use the default credentials two lines above. Try setting

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate on how this code would answer the question. As it is now, it has been automatically flagged as low quality.